# Bin time column and group multiple columns within each bin

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this, with one Date column and two categorical columns:

```
Date                        Feature1   Feature2
2019-01-06 19:15:52+00:00   A          K
2019-01-27 23:44:11+00:00   B          H
2019-01-29 16:50:31+00:00   A          K
2019-01-29 19:49:15+00:00   C          J
...                         ...        ...
```

I want to group the data into time bins of, say, 1 week and count how many Feature1 AND Feature2 occurrences are in each time bin. I tried the following approach, by first transforming the Date column to a datetime index, then using the Grouper function to bin in weekly buckets and then aggregate:

```
df = df.set_index(['Date'])
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df = df.sort_values(by='Date', ascending=True)
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='W', key='Date'), 'Feature1'])['Feature2'].agg(
    ['size', 'sum']).rename(columns={'size': 'Feature1', 'sum': 'Feature2'}).reset_index()
```

But this gives me only one of the Features correctly summed within the time bin. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here, any help?

***Edit 1***

This is a minimal example to generate my data:

```
import pandas as pd                                                                       
from datetime import datetime                                                             
import random                                                                             
import time                                                                               
import string                                                                             
                                                                                          
def random_date(seed):                                                                    
    random.seed(seed)                                                                     
    d = random.randint(1, int(time.time()))                                               
    return datetime.fromtimestamp(d).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')                        
                                                                                          
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['date', 'Feature1', 'Feature2'])                               
for i in range(1000):                                                                      
    date = random_date(i)                                                                 
    f1 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)                                              
    f2 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)                                              
    d = {'date': date, 'Feature1': f1, 'Feature2': f2}                                    
    df = df.append(d, ignore_index=True)                                                  
                                                                                          
df = df.set_index(['date'])                                                             
                                                                                        df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)                                                       
df = df.sort_values(by='date',ascending=True)
```

Comment: Can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and add expected output?

Comment: Thank you form mcve, but not understand how looks exected output? Need aggregate sum and size for both columns like my answer? Or smetning else?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with aggregate by [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
np.random.seed(2020)
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range('2015-01-01', periods=100).tolist() * 100,
                   'Feature1': np.random.choice(list(string.ascii_letters), size=10000),
                   'Feature2': np.random.choice(list(string.ascii_letters), size=10000)}) 

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df = df.melt('date', var_name='Feature', value_name='val').sort_values(by='date')

df = (df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='W', key='date'), 'Feature', 'val'])
       .size()
       .reset_index(name='count'))
print (df)
           date   Feature val  count
0    2015-01-04  Feature1   A      5
1    2015-01-04  Feature1   B     11
2    2015-01-04  Feature1   C      6
3    2015-01-04  Feature1   D      6
4    2015-01-04  Feature1   E     15
        ...       ...  ..    ...
1554 2015-04-12  Feature2   v      9
1555 2015-04-12  Feature2   w     14
1556 2015-04-12  Feature2   x     12
1557 2015-04-12  Feature2   y      8
1558 2015-04-12  Feature2   z      7

[1559 rows x 4 columns]
```